# spark streaming + kafka compatibility issue

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, spark-streaming-kafka

Will spark streaming compatible with kafka versions above 0.8.2.1?
Is writing custom receiver the only option to make spark streaming use kafka version above 0.9?

Answer (score 0):

I just added the "inter.broker.protocol.version=CURRENT_KAFKA_VERSION (e.g. 0.8.2 or 0.9.0.0)" in server.properties file. That will make the old 0.8.2.1 consumer to receive the data from new versions of kafka brokers.